# Left shift operator in python

Tags: python, c, bit-shift

I am trying to expand prefix-len(/y) notation from an ip-address. For example if 10.10.10.1/24 then I need uint32_t number of 4294967040(binary would be 11111111111111111111111100000000) for prefix-len(24). I can easily do this in C as follow:

```
(gdb) p/t 0xfffffff
$11 = 1111111111111111111111111111
(gdb) p/t 0xffffffff << 8 # (since 32-24)
$12 = 11111111111111111111111100000000
(gdb) p (0xffffffff << 8)                                     
$15 = 4294967040
```

But I tried the same in python but its not working. I am newbie to python so please explain me why is it not working and what would be right solution.(And I know there are lots of modules/packages to do this for me but I don't want to use them)

```
>>> bin(0xffffffff)                                           
'0b11111111111111111111111111111111'
>>> bin(0xffffffff << 8)
'0b1111111111111111111111111111111100000000'
>>> int(bin(0xffffffff << 8),2)                               
1099511627520
>>>
```

Comment: You have integer overflows in your "C" version which, when they are signed, even cause undefined behaviour. These overflows don't occur in Python, which is why your code doesn't work. Also, your `int(bin(..), 2)` is just plain nonsense, as it just converts a number to a string representation in binary and back again. Suggestion: Use `(2**24 - 1) << 8` where 8 and 24 sum up to the size of an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working, albeit not doing what you expect. You never told Python you wanted a 32-bit value, so you're getting an integer; Python supports arbitrarily large integers.

```
>>> ((1<<32) - 1) << 8
1099511627520
>>> 1<<123
10633823966279326983230456482242756608L
```

The behaviour you expected is silently discarding overflow, a behaviour C has for historical reasons. Even in C it's not a given it'll do that where you expect, however; int may well be 16, 64, or 18 bits wide. There are more specific types like uint32_t for when you want known sizes. To perform a similar truncation in Python, either store in a type with such a restricted size (like an array entry or ctypes.c_uint32), or mask explicitly.

```
>>> hex((0xffffffff<<8) & 0xffffffff)
'0xffffff00'
>>> hex(ctypes.c_uint32(0xffffffff00).value)
'0xffffff00L'
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought better to keep calculating with usual operators, and numbers.

```
>>> a=0xffffffff
>>> (a*256)%(2**32)
4294967040
```

Left shifting by 8 is multiplying by 256, and keeping the value on 32 bits is using the value modulo 2 power 32.